# Прямая речь или нет?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Мама хваталась за голову: «что за игры для девочки!» Все ли здесь правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Прямая речь начинается с прописной буквы: *Мама хваталась за голову: «Что за игры для девочки!»*

Если п. р. - член предложения, то есть оформляется без двоеточия, смотрим, образует ли она законченное предложение:

*С криком «Что за игры для девочки!» мама схватилась за голову.*

*Вспоминаю его обычное вежливое "Садитесь, пожалуйста".
Он хотел ответить "нет", но воздержался.*